# Does Con(ZF + Reinhardt) really imply Con(ZFC + I0)?

Tags: lo.logic, set-theory, large-cardinals, axiom-of-choice

The question is: if I assert in ZF that there exists a Reinhardt cardinal, do I really get a theory of higher consistency strength than when I assert in ZFC that there exists an I0 cardinal (the strongest large cardinal not known to be inconsistent with choice, as I understand)? This is implicit in the ordering of things on [Cantor's Attic](http://cantorsattic.info/Upper_attic), for example, but I've been unable to find a proof (granted, I don't necessarily have the best nose for where to look!).

One thing that worries me is that when there *is* a ZFC analog of a ZF statement, many equivalent formulations of the ZFC statement may become inequivalent in ZFC. So we don't have much assurance that the usual definition of a Reinhardt cardinal is "correct" in the absence of choice.

I think it should be clear that Con(ZF + Reinhardt) implies Con(ZF + I0). But again, it's not clear that ZF+I0 is equiconsistent with ZFC+I0.

It's apparently not possible to formulate Reinhardt cardinals in a first-order way, so I should really talk about NBG + Reinhardt, or maybe ZF($j$) + Reinhardt, where ZF($j$) has separation and replacement for formulas involving the function symbol $j$.

**EDIT**

Since this question has attracted a bounty from Joseph Van Name, maybe it's appropriate to update it a bit. Now, I'm not actually a set theorist, but it's not even clear to me that Con(ZF + Reinhardt) implies Con(ZFC + an inaccessible). So perhaps the question should really be: what large cardinal strength, if any, can we extract from the theory ZF + Reinhardt?

Comment: Related: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/87222/what-are-the-known-implications-of-there-exists-a-reinhardt-cardinal-in-the-th

Comment: I think the proof is supposed to be somewhere inside Woodin's supercompact set of papers with titles like "suitable extender sequences" or "suitable extender models". At least that's what I remember Woodin stating in one of his survey papers (but I already found the surveys a bit hard to digest so I won't try to go beyond that, and I certainly can't give a precise reference).

Comment: @Gro-Tsen: The word "Reinhardt" does not appear in either paper of the Suitable Extender Models.

Comment: @AsafKaragila I never even understood how many different papers there were supposed to be. In the book *Infinity: New Research Frontiers* (Cambridge 2011, Heller & Woodin eds.), Woodin writes in the article "The Realm of the Infinite", §4.3.2, that "by the results of Woodin (2009), the theory ZF+“There is a weak Reinhardt cardinal” *proves* the formal consistency of the theory ZFC+“There is a proper class of strongly (ω+1)-huge cardinals”" (emphasis his). Sadly, the reference "Woodin (2009)" is nowhere to be found! (contd.)

Comment: (contd.) In the [online version](http://logic.harvard.edu/EFI_Woodin_TheRealmOfTheInfinite.pdf) of the same text, the same statement (now in §1.3.2) is referred to a preprint called "Suitable extender sequences (July, 2009)". The papers published in 2010–2011 in *J. Math. Logic* are called "Suitable extender *models*" (emphasis mine), and the date suggests that they were published in time for the reference to be fixed in the survey article I mentioned: so is Woodin referring to yet another paper? So many mysteries.

Comment: @Gro-Tsen A search for "Suitable extender sequences" turns up [this](https://books.google.com/books?hl=en&lr=&id=w9R9f8pOqTIC&oi=fnd&pg=PA195&dq=woodin+tutorial+outline+suitable+extender+sequences+&ots=RBQmTeq9jp&sig=j36quds2AOEIbla1Y6cQHkVbXo0#v=onepage&q=woodin%20tutorial%20outline%20suitable%20extender%20sequences&f=false)  tutorial, but it doesn't seem to contain this result either.

Comment: The ordering of cardinals on Cantor's attic was based on the ZFC version of Reinhardt cardinals, which are inconsistent. Reinhardt had originally proposed his cardinals in ZFC.  The vestige of his idea lives on ZF.

Comment: @Joel: Correct me if I'm wrong, but if $\kappa$ is a Reinhardt cardinal, and $\lambda=\sup j^n(\kappa)$, then there is an elementary embedding from $L(V_{\lambda+1})$ to itself. No? So at least as far as ZF is concerned, Reinhardt implies I0.

Comment: Asaf, I believe that the question is whether from ZF+$\kappa$ is Reinhardt, you can get a model of ZFC+$I_0$. So you need to get that embedding inside a ZFC model.

Comment: @Joel: I know that, which is why this was a comment and not an answer. I was just trying to get a confirmation on my question. Despite having the advisor that I have, large cardinals (and very large cardinals) are still not so deep inside my comfort zone that I can make a remark like the one I made without someone double checking it.

Comment: Your remark is correct, but we don't usually consider $I_0$ without AC.

Comment: @Joel: Thanks. "Counterexample" to your statement, http://mathoverflow.net/questions/237662/the-axiom-i-0-in-the-absence-of-ac :-)

Comment: Just out of curiosity, for us non-set-theorists, what does "IO" stand for? Infernally oversized?

Comment: @bof That's a zero, not an O. At the top of the large cardinal hierarchy are four related axioms called I0, I1, I2, I3, in decreasing order of strength. They, like most _large_ large cardinal axioms, all have to do with elementary embeddings. So I had assumed that "I" stood for "imbedding". But I don't really know!

Comment: The "I" stands for "inconsistent", because it was initially thought that those embeddings might be inconsistent. Richard Laver disliked the notation, first because of that, and second, because the numbers $I_0$, $I_1$, $I_2$ and $I_3$ are in the wrong order.

Comment: @Joel: They are in the correct order: if we can continue this sequence, we will find a decreasing sequence of ordinals, hence an inconsistency! :-)

Comment: @Joel: I am still afraid of a possible inconsistency around $I_{3}$ arising from the algebras of elementary embeddings.

Comment: $Con(\text{ZF}+\text{Reinhardt})$ is a very weak assertion, below $Con(ZF+0^{\#})$. What you speak of is an incredibly weak variant of the wholeness axiom, known as $\text{BTEE}$.

Comment: @KeithMillar I'm intrigued -- this means that in the result of Goldberg referenced by Mohammad Golshani, DC must play a fundamental role, and suggests that the consistency strength of $ZF+Reinhardt+C$, where $C$ is some choice principle, must be very sensitive to precisely what $C$ is. If you could elaborate / provide references in an answer, I'd probably accept! In particular, why is this related to the wholeness axiom, and what does BTEE stand for?

Comment: Ah, ok. The inconsistency of Reinhardt cardinals follows from second-order ZFC (ZFC with second-order replacement), so ZFC + Reinhardt by itself is weaker than ZFC + $0^{\#}$ (but stronger than ineffability). Unfortunately, your question will likely never be answered before even an inner model for a supercompact comes out, because the only way we know "ZF(j) + Reinhardt" is stronger than "ZFC(j) + Woodin limit of Woodins" is by the inner model for such a Woodin limit of Woodins.

Comment: BTEE is detailed in this free paper https://www.impan.pl/pl/wydawnictwa/czasopisma-i-serie-wydawnicze/fundamenta-mathematicae/all/179/1/88640/the-gap-between-rm-i-3-and-the-wholeness-axiom. I am not sure what it stands for.

Answer (score 28):

The answer to your question is (almost) yes (almost is because of the addition of DC to the statement).

Recently Gabriel Goldberg has proved

> ''Con(NBG+DC+Reinhardt)$ \implies$ Con(ZFC+I0)''.

See the abstract of the talk by Gabriel Goldberg [Choiceless cardinals and I0](http://www.crm.cat/en/Activities/Curs_2016-2017/Documents/abstract-Goldberg.pdf).

(Thanks to [Rahman](https://mathoverflow.net/users/38866/rahman-m) for pointing this to me).

---

**Edit.** The result of Goldberg is now available,where indeed something stronger is proved. See [Even ordinals and the Kunen inconsistency](https://arxiv.org/abs/2006.01084). It is shown,  assuming DC, the existence of an elementary embedding from $V_{λ+3}$ to $V_{λ+3}$ implies the consistency of ZFC + $I_0$, while by a recent result of Schlutzenberg, an elementary embedding from $V_{λ+2}$ to $V_{λ+2}$ does not suffice. 
The paper of Schlutzenberg is
[On the consistency of ZF with an elementary embedding $j : V_{λ+2} → V_{λ+2}$](https://arxiv.org/abs/2006.01077).

Comment: Uhh, I don't see where in the linked abstract it says that. I says "come very close to improving this lower bound to Con(ZFC+I0)". It doesn't say that any such implication was actually proved.

Comment: I took notes during Gabe's talk yesterday and he indeed outlined of proof of $\operatorname{NBG} + \operatorname{DC} + \text{Reinhardt} \vdash \operatorname{Con}(\operatorname{ZFC} + \operatorname{I_0})$. The use of $\operatorname{DC}$ - according to Gabe - is unfortunate, but it's unknown how to avoid it for now. If Gabe is fine with it (I'll ask him later today), I'd be happy to share my notes in case anyone is interested in them.

Comment: @Stefan Thanks Stefan, I edited the answer to make the statement precise. Surely, I'm interested to see the notes

Comment: @Stefan For some reason, I cannot click on the link.

Comment: @Victoria My bad. [This link](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0ByqvTqmmvRala2RmOS1ITEFGZG8) should work.

Comment: With Gabe's permission, I uploaded my notes [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0ByqvTqmmvRala2RmOS1ITEFGZG8/view). He is also finalizing a paper on the subject, so keep an eye out for that. (Sorry about the bad handwriting - it was freezing cold inside the lecture hall.)

Comment: The link in my previous comment no longer works. Here is an [updated link to Gabe's talk](https://drive.google.com/file/d/17gRXjkzJRPnYC1ltfGUmHiUEs-bdI2__/view?usp=sharing).

Answer (score 11):

Regarding the edit, one can easily show some simple lower bounds for a Reinhardt cardinal that are far stronger than an inaccessible cardinal. For example, if $\kappa$ is a Reinhardt cardinal, assuming ZF only, then it is clear that $\kappa$ is inaccessible and weakly compact and much more in $L$, because it is the critical point of an elementary embedding $j:V\to V$, which therefore gives rise to an elementary embedding $j\upharpoonright L:L\to L$, and any such $\kappa$ must be inaccessible in $L$ and weakly compact in $L$ and much more. Indeed, one easily gets the consistency of a measurable cardinal, since if $\mu$ is the measure on $\kappa$ induced by the original embedding $j:V\to V$, then $L[\mu]$ will be the canonical inner model in which $\kappa$ is measurable.

It seems to me that one will be able to carry this argument completely through the standard inner model of large cardinals. Thus, from a Reinhardt cardinal in ZF set theory, I expect that the critical point $\kappa$ of the corresponding embedding $j:V\to V$ will be very large in the corresponding core models.

What is less clear to me is the extent to which one gets models of ZFC plus $\kappa$ has large cardinal properties that are not witnessed by the standard inner model theory, and this is how one should interpret the question.

Answer (score 2):

Mohammed Golshani's link doesn't work, so I have reconstructed a sketch of a proof. The key fact is this (You can find a proof in most Set Theory textbooks):

**Theorem:** If $DC_\omega$ holds and $D$ is an $\omega_1$-complete ultrafilter, then the ultraproduct of $N$ by $D$ is well-founded, for any inner model $N$.

**Theorem:** If $DC_\lambda$ holds and $\kappa$ is $I0$ (With target $\lambda$) if and only if there is a non-principal $\kappa$-complete $L(V_{\lambda+1})$-ultrafilter on $V_{\lambda+1}$.

*Proof.* Let $D$ be such an ultrafilter. To verify the existence of a such an ultraproduct, we can code elements of $D$ as function $F: X^{\lt\lambda}\rightarrow X'$ for every set $X'=\{\chi_x|x\in V_{\lambda+1}\}$, there is a function $f: \lambda\rightarrow X$, such that $f(\chi_x)\in\chi_x$, and so some $A\in D$, such that $\{\chi_x|x\in A\}$ admits a Choice function. Then if $M\cong Ult_D(L(V_{\lambda+1}))$ is the ultrapower $M\ni V_{\lambda+1}$. $L(V_{\lambda+1})$ inherits a well-order for each element (A well order not necessarily in $L(V_{\lambda+1})$ from $L(V_{\lambda+1})$. Then by condensation $M= L(V_{\lambda+1})$ and $\kappa$ is the critical point of the ultrapower embedding $k_D: L(V_{\lambda+1})\prec L(V_{\lambda+1})$. For the other direction, define an ultrafilter $D=\{X\subseteq V_{\lambda+1}|j\restriction V_\lambda\in j(X)\}$. This satisfies all the necessary properties.◼

**Theorem:** If $\kappa$ is Reinhardt, indeed even the critical point of $j: V_{\lambda+2}\prec V_{\lambda+2}$, then $\kappa$ is $I0$.

*Proof.* Let $\kappa$ Reinhardt as witnessed by $j: V\prec V$, and let $\lambda$ be the least fixed point above $\kappa$. Let $D=\{X\subseteq V_{\lambda+1}|j\restriction V_\lambda\in j(X)\}\cap L(V_{\lambda+1})$. Then $D$ satisfies all the necessary properties. The second case is not much trickier, as it uses the same argument.◼

Comment: DC is a red herring for your first theorem. For an ultrapower $M^\kappa/D$ to be elementary equivalent to $M$ you need to have $\sf AC_\kappa$ modulo $D$. Namely, for any family $\{A_\alpha\mid\alpha<\kappa\}$ of non-empty sets, there is $A\in D$ such that $\{A_\alpha\mid\alpha\in A\}$ admits a choice function. This is exactly the amount of choice necessary for Łoś to work and for you to get elementarity. Otherwise the ultrapower is not even extensional.

Comment: (Let me qualify my previous remark, and say that you need choice from families of sets in $M$. So if $M$ is a model of choice, e.g. HOD, you might just have this without needing more. But the point stands: DC is irrelevant here.)

Comment: Anything to respond to that?

Comment: Sorry. I forgot about your post. I will adjust by answer later on today.

Comment: You sort of ignored my remark that DC is certainly not enough for the ultrapower argument to work, since that still shows in your answer; and in your last theorem you haven't at all justified why $\sf DC_\lambda$ holds, since $\lambda$ is much larger than $\kappa$, it's not something you can just say "Oh, there's a small forcing to fix that".

Comment: I am absolutely not sure that $DC_\lambda$ holds. My arguments presuppose it does. My idea was that you could get Choice back in $V_\kappa$ while preserving that $\kappa$ is Reinhardt. Then, you could use the fact that there is an $I0$ cardinal below it, to get a model of ZFC+$I0$. But, it was just an idea. As for your other comment, $L(V_{\lambda+1})$ inherits a well-order for each element (A well order not necessarily in $L(V_{\lambda+1})$ from $L(V_{\lambda+1})$.

Comment: Yes, it's true that $L(V_{\lambda+1})$ inherits a well-orderings from $V$. But this pressuposes that choice holds in $V$. If there is a Reinhardt cardinal, choice fails. As I wrote to begin with, DC is kind of a red herring here.

Comment: No, it inherits its well-order from $V_{\lambda+1}$. That is why the argument works.

Comment: I should explain my comment. You can use $DC_\lambda$ to get a well-order for $V_{\lambda+1}$. This well-order is not in $L(V_{\lambda+1})$. But, there is still a well-order.

Comment: You cannot prove that $V_{\lambda+1}$ can be well-ordered just by assuming $\sf DC_\lambda$ holds. (I miscounted in a previous comment which is now deleted.) An easy example is that $\sf DC$ need not imply that the real numbers can be well-ordered.